# Large Data Processing: Removing lines in one text document found in another

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, grep, word-processing

I have 2 large text files (~500M, ~15GB ea) That look like this:

FileP.txt:

```
test@test.com:testtest 
test@test.com1:testtest1
test@test.com2:testtest2
test@test.com3:testtest3
test@test.com4:testtest4
```

FileE.txt

```
test@test.com:testtest
test@test.com0:testtest0
test@test.com2:testtest2
test@test.com3:testtest3
test@test.com5:testtest5
```

(Notice how `FileE.txt` has lines that aren't in `FileP.txt`. I don't want those included. Bold lines are lines that should end up in `output.txt`, as they're not in `FileE.txt`.)

I want to run `FileE.txt` against `FileP.txt` and remove all the lines that were found in `FileE.txt` from `FileP.txt` and output into a new file.

It should look like this:

Output.txt:

```
test@test.com1:testtest1
test@test.com4:testtest4
```

I tried a few commands,

Here's my grep command:

```
$ grep -Fvxf FileE.txt FileP.txt > output.txt
```

However, I get this error (Obviously because the files are too large):

```
grep: memory exhausted
```

For those interested, running `$ ulimit -a` returns:

```
core file size          (blocks, -c) unlimited
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
open files                      (-n) 256
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 2032
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) 256
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
```

So my question is, what would be the most efficient & easiest way to complete this process?

NOTE: Files are not sorted.

Comment: Are the files guaranteed to be sorted? Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your question to make it clearer and more complete.

Comment: Sort the files, do a `diff FileP.txt File.txt` and keep only the lines prefixed with `<`?

Comment: @Scott Done. How would I keep lines only prefixed with <? I've never used Diff. Does it make one large folder with < prefixed to the lines with the difference? Does this also keep the lines that are available in  FileE.txt that don't exist in FileP.txt?

Comment: @JakeGouldI thought about that, honestly. I have to stay in CL :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the files are sorted, do

```
comm -23 fileP.txt fileE.txt
```

`comm` compares two sorted files, looking for lines that they have in common. 
For example, given this file of colors whose names begin with consonants:

```
blue
green
purple
red
white
yellow
```

and this list of colors whose names end with vowels:

```
blue
indigo
orange
purple
white
```

the command `comm colors1 colors2` produces this output:

```
                blue
green
        indigo
        orange
                purple
red
                white
yellow
```

where:
the first column contains colors that begin and end with consonants
(in `colors1` but not `colors2`),
the second column contains colors that begin and end with vowels
(in `colors2` but not `colors1`),
and the third column contains colors that begin with consonants
and end with vowels (in both `colors1` and `colors2`). 
For your files (shown in your question), `comm fileP.txt fileE.txt` produces

```
                test@test.com:testtest
        test@test.com0:testtest0
test@test.com1:testtest1
                test@test.com2:testtest2
                test@test.com3:testtest3
test@test.com4:testtest4
        test@test.com5:testtest5
```

The options are a little non-intuitive: `-23` means
suppress the second and third columns, showing only the first
(lines that are in the first file but not the second). 
So,

```
$ comm -23 fileP.txt fileE.txt
test@test.com1:testtest1
test@test.com4:testtest4
```

Note that this will not work correctly if the files are not sorted. 
It the files aren’t sorted, sort them.

Answer (score 0):

To enlarge on [a comment by xenoid](https://superuser.com/q/1341039/150988#comment2006715_1341039), sort the files and type

```
diff fileP.txt fileE.txt | sed -n 's/^< //p'
```

The output of `diff` shows the lines that are in only the first file,
preceded by `<` ,
and the lines that are in only the second file, preceded by `>` . 
The `sed` selects only the lines that begin with `<`  and strips it off.